# complex DIV overlapping and visibility with CSS

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm looking to have an image object that looks like it's "pinned" to the side of my fixed-width page. but it seems to be contradictory - in order to style it, the div with the image has to be in a separate div than the main content, but in order for it to work in the layout, the div with the image can't be a separate div from the main content.

It's hard to explain in words, so take a look at this demo I whipped up instead. if you will:
http://www.hinchy.us/demo.html

Check the image in the source of that page for more information on what I want.

Comment: Where is your CSS? For a complex question like this, it would be helpful if you provided a demo.

Comment: okay, I have a complete demo in the post now. if you still want the example image, the URL to it is in a comment in the source of the demo (gotta love the new user restrictions on stack overflow!!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.orange { position:relative; z-index:5; }
```

To get the orange above the green line. Does IE6/IE7 matter?

Answer (score 0):

```
#red { z-index: 3; }
#green-right{ z-index: 2; }
.blue { z-index: 4; width: 950px; }
.orange { left: auto; right: -140px; margin-left: -108px; -margin-right: 0px; }
```

I have added these lines to the bottom of your styles to resolve the issue in IE6/7.  Given the buggy box model of older IE, I would recommend a different sizing/positioning scheme for the red and blue boxes, so they have properly matched widths in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

So "pinned" meaning even if you scroll the page it stays fixed at the top and right? If that's the case you'd want:

```
.orange {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
```